# How to save app instance specific state

Tags: rally

I'd like to save the user selection of a Rally artifact so that when the page is reloaded details about that artifact are displayed. There may be several instances of the app on the smae dashboard; whats the best way to uniquely identify a specific instance. I plan to use the preferences api to save the state.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about SDK 2.0p3:  Each copy of the app has a unique ID that you can use "getAppID()" to find.  However, if you use the updateSettingsValues, it will save it uniquely by AppID automatically.  Sadly, the updateSettingsValues is app specific only, not user or project specific.

Comment: I hope they remedy this in the future. Settings/preferences per app are not going to be as useful as per user, and it is also a shame that there is no developer access to the actual settings menu (cog in upper-right) at the moment.